# Get only one column of data depending on the date

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, etl

I have an excel file that is I am greeting weekly and the file column is written as “day01” “day02” and so on. “01” represent the dates and I am only supposed to get that every week depending on what date our calendar is, for instance if today is 5/3/2020 than that means I only will get column “day01” and next week I am suppose to get “day02”. I am using an ssis package with nested for loop and for each loop container. How can I get only one week of data from excel every week depending on the date.
I am stuck I need help please it’s for my school project.
The excel file has the following column

-ID integer unique values)

- “day01” (currency)

-“day02” (currency)

-“day03” (currency)

-“day04” ....

I want to get for each ID one week of data that is “day01” which “day01” must much with the calendar, and for next week the same thing.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I am not able to attack any data because I am still new to stack but I have edited my question.

Comment: how do you get which week it is?

Comment: Anyway. here is a hint. Figure out the week and build dynamic sql in a parameter and use an OLEDB connection and query to load results.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for the school project, use variables. Make sure that the loop picks and extracts only the MAX day value (if they are consecutive and each week gets a day n+1 name). It will allow you to extract only the latest week of data (or manually specify which one week you want, for a one time load).

In the real project, I would rather pull all data from the Excel file into a staging table (especially important if the Excel is not auto generated and users have access to it), review and validate, and then take the last week (or any week you need) and work with it further..